# Problem this enumerate

Tags: horizontal-alignment, math-operators

how to make items a) and b) be at the same distance from each
other, perhaps it's a matter of numbering, how can everything be numbered as a) b) c) and so on?
[image]

```
\begin{flushleft}
$ a)\; D = (B - A) \cup (A - (B \cup C)) \cup (C - A)\\* $
$ A = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}  $
$ B = \{2,5,6,9,10\}  $
$ C = \{4,7,8,11,12\} \\* $
$ b)\; A = \{1,2,8\} $
$ B = \{6,7\} $
$ C = \{2,3,4,5,7\} $
\end{flushleft}
```

Comment: Why are you using a `flushleft` here in the first place and not a proper list? For good lists see the `enumitem` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

With use of the `enumerate` list of `enumitem` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph{*}), align=left, leftmargin=*]
\item   $D = (B - A) \cup (A - (B \cup C)) \cup (C - A)$
\item   $A = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$
\item   $B = \{2,5,6,9,10\}$
\item   $C = \{4,7,8,11,12\}$
\item   $A = \{1,2,8\}$
\item   $B = \{6,7\}$
\item   $C = \{2,3,4,5,7\}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```